# how to plot only most abundant species in NMDS?

Tags: r, vegan

I need to plot an ordination plot showing only let s say the 20 most abundant species.

I tried to do the sum of the species colunm and then select only a certain sum value:

```
abu <- colSums(dune)
abu
sol <- metaMDS(dune)
sol
plot(sol, type="text", display="species", select = abu > 40)
```

I get this error: select is not a graphical parameter

I would expect to see only small number of species but it does not happen,
how do you show only a small number of species in the NMDS plot?

Comment: Please create a working example. I have no `spp1.hell` variable on my computer.

Comment: I have put the example of the dune dataframe from vegan, is it missing in the post? I would like to know how I could only show the most abundant species in the plot not all of them.

Comment: In that case, please remove the first bit of code from your post (because I can't run it), and focus only on the dune data set. What is wrong with it? What did you try? Also, I strongly suspect that `nothing happens` is not true, because what I would *expect* it to happen is throw an informative error message such as "select is not a graphical parameter". Also, do you want to select the species *prior* to running `metaMDS`, or only omit some species from being plotted?

Comment: I edited the question. I wanted to try to select only species with an abundance higher than 40 to show only those in the NMDS plot but it just gives the error, so I would like to know how I can omit only the less abudant species from the NMDS plot and show let s say the 10 most abundant ones. I hope I have explained myself better.

Answer (score 1):

This is not straightforward. You are getting an error because select is not a parameter for the plot. Unfortunately, the result of the analysis is not a data.frame that could be handled easily (e.g. with tidyverse), and even more unfortunately, the plot() function called is not your standard plot, but a method defined specifically for objects of this class. The authors of this method did not foresee your need, and therefore, we must make the plot manually. But to do that, we need to understand what is plotting and how.

Let us find out more about the object `sol`:

```
class(sol)
# [1] "metaMDS" "monoMDS"
methods(class="metaMDS")
# [1] goodness    nobs        plot        points      print       scores      sppscores<- text
```

Oh good, we have a plot method. After a moment of digging, we find it in the `vegan` package (not exported, so we need to access it via `vegan:::plot.metaMDS`). It appears to be a wrapper around a function called `ordiplot`. We edit the function with `edit()` to figure out what it is doing. Essentially, it boils down to the following (with loads of unnecessary code):

```
Y <- scores(sol, display="species")
plot(Y, type="n")
text(Y[,1], Y[,2], rownames(Y), col="red")
```

This is, more or less, your plot. Choosing the species to show is now trivial, but first we must make sure that rows of Y are in the same order as columns of dune:

```
all(colnames(dune) == rownames(Y))
Y.sel <- Y[colSums(dune) > 40, ]
plot(Y.sel[,1], Y.sel[,2], type="n", xlim=c(-.8, .8), ylim=c(-.4, .4))
text(Y.sel[,1], Y.sel[,2], rownames(Y.sel), col="red")
```

[image]

We can of course make a much nicer plot. For example, with ggplot (it is definitely possible to make a much nicer plot with base R as well). We could actually show the abundance of the plants using the size esthetics:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

Y <- data.frame(Y)
Y$abundance <- colSums(dune)
Y$labels <- rownames(Y)

ggplot(Y, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, size=abundance)) +
   geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label=labels)) + 
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

To filter the species by abundance, we now can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
Y %>% filter(abundance > 40) %>%
  ggplot(Y, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, size=abundance)) +
    geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label=labels)) + 
    theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for! thanks a lot for the clear explanation of the steps and for making me learn a new code!

Comment: Thank you. Generally, if you are happy with an answer, please upvote and accept; this is important if the person answering has reputation well below 1000 points (higher reputation gives additional permissions on the site).

Comment: With an ordination, you should add `coord_equal()` so the plot is correctly scaled (makes little difference in this case)